# Get post_meta image url based on ID

Tags: php, database, wordpress

So i'd like to extract the image url from the database on one of my post_meta, but I'm unsure how to target that.

Here is the steps that I'm taking:

Here is what's under the `wp_postmeta` table in the database:
[image]

If I navigate to `wp_posts` - I get the `meta_value` post with my url inside as such:
[image]

---

When I do `$test = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'full_image');` I get the following:
[image]

How does one extract the image url from `wp_posts` based on `$post->ID`? I'm having the hardest time targeting it.

---

**UPDATE**:

If I do `var_dump(get_attached_media('image', $post->ID));` - I get the following results:
[image]

How do I grab the `guid` url?

Comment: Are you looking for the_post_thumbnail from a post or extracting a file from your library?

Comment: @gael, extracting a file from a post that has ACF Image field but I'm unable to use get_field because it's inside an mu-plugins directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using this method:

`$this->set_full_image(wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'full_image', true), 'large'));`

The reason that I wasn't getting any results back is because `get_post_meta` was returning an array and not a single value so I had to set true at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're making it too hard. 
All you need to is use  [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)

```
$test = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'full_image', true);
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $test[0] );
```

Comment: the problem is that I don't need the thumbnail which has another image, this is using ACF Image field .. which I can't use the `get_field` call because it's inside an `mu-plugin` .. So I feel like my best bet is to somehow try to extract the image from the post.

Comment: Edited to reflect using your Field

Comment: Thanks for all the help @KGreene, I ended up having to add true at the end of get_post_meta and then use wp_get_attachment_image_url.

Answer (score 0):

To grab the `guid` from your array, you will have to call it like that:

```
<?php    
    $image = get_attached_media('image', $post->ID);
    $image_guid = $image['guid'];
    echo $image_guid; //will echo the guid URL
?>
```

Comment: This is giving me an null return - Appreciate the help tho!